# How to configure Gradle for a Kotlin multi-platform project with multiple targets?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

For my Kotlin JVM project I have 2 different implementations for expected declarations of classes/functions. I'm using Kotlin multi-platform features with the expect/actual system. Here's the project structure:

```
|-- actual1           (sub-module)
    |-- src/          (actual declarations for the first target)
    |-- build.gradle
|-- actual2           (sub-module)
    |-- src/          (actual declarations for the second target)
    |-- build.gradle
|-- src/              (common code + expected declarations)
|-- build.gradle
```

How should I go about configuring Gradle such that I can switch between using `actual1` or `actual2` at compile time with for example a compiler flag?